# Are two nilpotent $3\times3$ matrices with rank 2 always similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, nilpotence

If we have any two nilpotent $3\times3$ matrices $A, B$ with rank $2$, are they always similar?

I started by considering their nullity, which is $1$. Then, since they are nilpotent, their only eigenvalue is $0$, thus their eigenspaces are their nullspaces.

Since their nullity is $1$, then their JCF must only have one jordan block, which means their JCF is the same (a $3\times3$ jordan block with $0$ as the diagonal), thus they are similar.

My reasoning may be flawed, please give me some insight.

Comment: Your argument looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes, since they have the same Jordan canonical form, both are similar to the same triangular matrix. So they must be similar (equivalence relation).